# Reduce resource consumption for hidden elements with phonegap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, performance, cordova

I am writing a web app with html/js/css and phonegap. 
I have two sections in the page, and each of them is a long list. At the same time, only one is visible. When the lists are very long the performance is getting worse. 
Does the browser release resources for display:none elements? If not, how can I conveniently release the resources for the hidden section (and restore it quickly when needed)?

Comment: If this is still a problem, may I know how you handle the scrolling through your list? The bottleneck might be here. I would suggest to take a look at the `iScroll 4` library. It works for Android 2.3+ and iOS as far as I know. Also don't try to use alot of text-shadows, gradients and other CSS3 goodness in long lists. These tend to be a performance hog.

Answer (score 0):

I know exactly what you mean about bad performance when it comes to long lists. Looks like screen tearing for a second, then it catches up. Place the below at the top level (try the body{}) of your CSS file:

```
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
```

Comment: Why adding this to body makes my body background not show? Seems suggested for ios, but buggy in android.

Comment: Really? That is weird. But does it fix your problem? The css rules above are used to remove 3D transformations and make them 2D which increases performance. Try adding them to *{} instead. If that doesnt work, add them to the element and keep going up a level until it works. I really have no idea why it would break a background though. Unless of course you are doing some 3D transformations of your background.

Comment: The fix suggested here is not a 'magic fix-it-all' solution. You should note that while 3D animations are definitely much better for Mobile devices than their 2D counterpart. This answer doesn't cause the whole screen to be rendered over the videocard rather than CPU. I only use them when actually animating. Otherwise I'd just use `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;` on parent elements of 3D animated objects. It'd prevents the flickering for some reason.